# Configure Redis Bull Board

Tags: node.js, redis, queue, bull

I am trying to setup a Bull Board in order to view my Redis Queue but I am always getting "page address isn't valid" when I access `0.0.0.0:8000/admin/queues`

I am following the Bull Board [documentation](https://github.com/felixmosh/bull-board) for their Hello World example.

My Express server is running on `0.0.0.0:8000`
My Redis server is running on `http://0.0.0.0:6379` and I am able to add and run jobs successfully (tested with the `redis-cli`).

Questions:

1. The documentation says to install `rpm i @bull-board/express` but the Hello World example uses the `@bull-board/api` package so I installed that as well in my debugging. Should I have to do this?

Can anybody see where I am going wrong here?

---

**CODE:**

**Package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@bull-board/api": "^3.7.0",
    "@bull-board/express": "^3.7.0",
    "bull": "^4.1.1",
    ...other packages
  }
```

**Redis Config**

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || '0.0.0.0',
};
```

**Redis Report Notification Queue**

```
const Bull = require('bull')
const redisConfig = require('../config');

// Create Queue
const reportNotificationsQueue = new Bull('reportNotifications', {
  redis: redisConfig
})

// Producer: adds job to queue
const addReportNotification = (data) => {
  reportNotificationsQueue.add(data)
}

// Consumer: function to run 
const sendReportNotification = async (job) => {
  console.log('Job Data',job.data)
  // ... job logic
}

// Process Queue
reportNotificationsQueue.process(sendReportNotification)

module.exports = {
  reportNotificationsQueue,
  addReportNotification
}
```

**Express Server Setup**

```
/* IMPORTS */
const redis = require('redis');
const redisConfig = require('../redis/config');
const { createBullBoard } = require('@bull-board/api')
const { BullAdapter } = require('@bull-board/api/bullAdapter')
const { ExpressAdapter } = require('@bull-board/express')
const { reportNotificationsQueue } = require('../redis/queues/reportNotifications')

...more express configurations

/* Redis: client */
const redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConfig);
redisClient.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(`Redis Connection Established: http://${redisConfig.host}:${redisConfig.port}`);
});
redisClient.on('error', () => {
  console.error('Redis Failed To Establish Connection');
});
/* Redis: bull board */
const serverAdapter = new ExpressAdapter();
const { addQueue, removeQueue, setQueues, replaceQueues } = createBullBoard({
  queues: [
    new BullAdapter(reportNotificationsQueue),
  ],
  serverAdapter: serverAdapter
})
serverAdapter.setBasePath('/admin/queues')
app.use('/admin/queues', serverAdapter.getRouter());

...more express configurations
```

Comment: Have you tried "localhost" instead of "0.0.0.0"?